# Regex javascript to escape some chars

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I need to develop a function in javascript that escapes some chars and then returns the cleaner string.

for example I need to prefix all those chars:

```
^ * +  ?  [  ]
```

by \

from:

```
this is a [string] that ^ contains some ? chars
```

To

```
this is a \\[string\\] that \\^ contains some \\? chars
```

Best regards

Comment: you mean echap or escape ??

Comment: This is not really a duplicate, it actually asks for a javascript function to escape JQL (jira query language) strings. See @Amine's comment below. I would suggest adding "jql" and "jira" as labels to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a REGEX to do so:

```
'asdas^asdas [asd]'.replace(/([\^\*\+\?\[\]])/g, '\\$1')
```

Explanation:

- `(` : captures a group
- `[` : any of those
- `\^\*\+\?\[\]` : all the chars you want, escaped
- `.replace` : replace those who match (any of the chars you choose, save capturing group
- `$1` the first capturing group, prefixed by
- `//` a single slash, escaped

Comment: Thanks Luan I tried your regex But it return **asdas\^asdas \[asd\]**

Comment: Here it returns `"asdas\^asdas \[asd\]"`. I'm trying on chrome console and node v6.4.0. If you want double slashes, use quadruple slashes (escaped) in the replace part (`'\\\\$1'`). Are you sure the brackets are not escaped? What exact code are you running?

Comment: I tried this it works **'asdas^asdas [asd]'.replace(/([\^\*\+\?\[\]])/g, '\\\\$1')**

Comment: Oh, you probably forgot the *g*. The *g* makes it global, that is, replace every occurrence, otherwise it will just do the first.

Comment: I need to make Jira JQL request  and there is some reserved characters which I need to escape theme

Comment: You need to escape every char (well, not every, but you can escape every one to be sure). If you want these chars `^*+?[]`, use `\^\*\+\?\[\]` (single slash before each).

Comment: Thanks @Luna it works